Pybind11: typedef and incompatible function arguments error
In c++ I defined:
typedef std::tuple<int, int, int> Type;
typedef std::tuple<int, int, int, int> Shape;

class Properties {
public:
    Properties() {}
    Properties(Type t_, Shape s_) : t{t_}, s{s_}, {}
        ...
private:
    Type t;
    Shape s;
}

I tried to bind with pybind11 in this way:
PYBIND11_MODULE(pybind_test, m)
{
    py::class_<Type>(m, "Type")
        .def(py::init<>())
        .def(py::init<int, int, int>());

    py::class_<Shape>(m, "Shape")
        .def(py::init<>())
        .def(py::init<int, int, int, int>());

    py::class_<Properties>(m, "Properties")
        .def(py::init<>())
        .def(py::init<Type, Shape>());
        ...
}

When I try to use it on python:
...
>>> type = Type(0,8,1)
>>> shape = Shape(10,10,10,10)
>>> prop = Properties(type, shape)

it gives me this error:
TypeError: __init__(): incompatible constructor arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. pybind_test.Properties()
    2. pybind_test.Properties(arg0: Tuple[int, int, int], arg1: Tuple[int, int, int, int])

Any idea on how to solve it?

From docs: "... std::tuple<> are already supported out of the box" -- looks like that standard support for tuples takes precedence. Do you really need to have Type and Shape bound as separate types, instead of just using tuples? Not like you're adding any extra functionality.

I'd like to have my own classes with Type and Shape name, instead of using Type and Shape, that's why i used typedef. And that error sounds a bit strange.
